# Receiving a vague error when I run a Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a simple web application in Blazor that displays a listing of games using an HTML table.

I wrote some code, but when I try to run it, I just get this error:

```
An unhandled error has occurred
```

I'm using an API that returns a listing of games in JSON format. I know the API is ok, because it works fine when I tested it using Postman.

Here is my code:

```
var gamesList= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GameData[]>("http://1.1.1.1/api/gamedata");


<table>
    <th>Games</th>
            @foreach (var game in gamesList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@game.Title</td>
                    <td>@game.Genre</td>
                    <td>@game.Price</td>
                </tr>
            }
</table>
```

Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess (not having used Blazor) is that you are getting an exception somewhere. Test for null coming back from your GET. Just because you can reach that URL from your desktop using Postman doesn't mean your website (wherever it is running) can do the same

Comment: For future reference, when this occurs during development the details of the exception should be logged in your browsers console. That should provide more info on what's going wrong.

Comment: Please add tag what hosting model you are using `blazor-server-side` or `blazor-client-side`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be something like the following:

```
@inject HttpClient Http


@if (gamesList == null)
{
   <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach (var game in gamesList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@game.Title</td>
                <td>@game.Genre</td>
                <td>@game.Price</td>
            </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
   </table>
 }

 @code {
    private GameData[] gamesList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {

      gamesList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GameData[]> 
          ("gamedata");

    }

}
```

Also ensure that you've got this code in your Program.Main method:

```
  var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
  builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

  builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = 
               new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

  await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Note: There might be a couple of reasons to this error. I tend to believe it is due to not checking if gamesList is null, which it is when the table is being rendered. It is important to understand that when you call the OnInitialisedAsync method, control is yielded to the calling code (the framework) which starts rendering the table before your async method returns, which means that gamesList is still null, raising an exception.

Hope this works...

Comment: Thanks! What is all that code doing relates to builder? I don’t have anything like that in my project anywhere.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell This builder code relates to Blazor WebAssembly, if you are using Server hosting model then this code will be different.

Comment: @Xeevis would every else be the same though in regard to the answer provided by enet?  thanks!